# Removing link from quick launch bar

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, quick-launch

I have a link in the quick launch bar that is obsolete, how do I remove it?  The page had 3 owners before. I didn't do it nor do I understand how they did it.

Answer (score 2):

To edit navigation on your site, first click **Site Actions** -> **Site Settings**.

If the publishing infrastructure feature has been activated on the site collection, you'll be able to change the quick launch and top navigation bar by clicking "**Navigation**" under the **"Look and Feel"** heading.

If the publishing infrastructure feature has **not** been activated on the site collection, you'll be able to change the quick launch by clicking "**Quick Launch**" under the **"Look and Feel"** heading.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Site Actions** --> **Site Settings** --> **Look and Feel** --> **Navigation**

Under **Current Navigation**, look for the link and click on it and **Delete**.